# How can I parametrize a pytest fixture with command line arguments?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I need to get arguments from command line and use them for fixture parametrizing (I need to pass them to fixture decorator). pytest_addoption can get arguments from cmd, but I can extract them only inside of some fixture, because I need request fixture for this. The problem is that I need these cmd arguments OUTSIDE of fixtures. I do not want to parametrize tests, I need to parametrize a fixture with some setup and teardown. Is there some way to solve this problem?

Some example. I want to test /add/post Api method. I want to test it with several users - for example, I want to request this api method with user1, then with user2 and after that with user3. So I need to parametrize my fixture with a list of users. AND I WANT TO PASS THIS LIST OF USER INTO MY TESTS VIA CMD. Kinda like this:
python -m pytest my_test.py --users="user1 user2 user3"

conftest.py:

```
import pytest

from some_dir import add_a_new_post_as_some_user, 


@pytest.fixture(params=users) # I NEED TO GET users FROM CMD
def add_post(request):
    current_user = request.param
    response = add_a_new_post_as_some_user(user)
    yield current_user, response.status_code
    delete_this_post(response.json()["some_post_id"])
```

test.py:

```
def test_add_post_as_some_user(add_post):
    user, status_code = add_post
    assert status_code == 200, f"Problems with user {user}"
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting question. But, as written, it leaves *a lot* to the reader's imagination. I think this question would benefit from a working example (w/o the CLI) that shows what you're trying to achieve with the CLI, and how you've tried to implement it.

Comment: @PaulH Thank you for your advice, I added some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `conftest.py`, get the command line argument with:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--users", action="store", default=None, help="Users list"
    )
```

Then use the [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_generate_tests) function to parametrize the fixture:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "add_post" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("add_post", metafunc.config.getoption("--users").split(","))


@pytest.fixture()
def add_post(request):
    current_user = request.param
    response = add_a_new_post_as_some_user(user)
    yield current_user, response.status_code
    delete_this_post(response.json()["some_post_id"])
```

Now, tests using the fixture `add_post` will be parametrized with the users taken from the command line when running with `pytest --users user1,user2`, for example.